# Allocate more than 4GB memory in C

Tags: c

I need to allocate more than 4GB memory in my C program (running on Windows - 64 bit).
Obviously using just `malloc` does not solve the problem.

I've read some of the previous posts in this manner, and it seems like [`VirtualAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) may solve my issue.
I tried to use it, and I don't understand all the parameters associated with this function. 
I think I need to define exactly the address in which the memory should be allocated, but I don't know how to do it.
Is there a simple information about it, or a simple example that I can use?

I also do not need to allocate all in one chunk, so it might be easier. Any alternative way to allocate more than 4gb memory will also be accepted.

Thanks.

Comment: *"Obviously using just "malloc" does not solve the problem."* -- why not ? If it's a 64 bit program then you should be able to malloc way more than 4 GB without any problems. You're not doing something silly, like using an `int` expression to calculate the size passed to `malloc` are you ?

Comment: OS usage notwithstanding, you're *compiling* to a 64bit program target, *right*?

Comment: hey, uhm ... just wanted to throw this in because nobody else will : *"I need to allocate more than 4GB memory"* -- **you're doing it wrong**. Just sayian.

Comment: @specializt not necessarily... data compression can use arbitrarily large amounts of memory for example

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) of VirtualAlloc, the first parameter is optional. Just pass in NULL and let Windows decide where to allocate memory

Comment: @specializt: What if OP has do deal with a single coherent dataset several GiBs large? I have to deal with datasets of this kind quite regularly (ultra highspeed volumetric OCT data; 6GB per second, in some cases a single uninterrupted, continuous scan amounts to over 20GiB of raw interferometer fringe sample data).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with needing this much memory @specializt but yes, you might have to go to OS specific functions in order to use it efficiently.

Comment: literally all of you : google "segmentation". I know these concepts look terrifying for beginners - and some might even consider them "overkill" but .... they're not. In fact they're everydays work. If you cant segment your data your skills arent quite up to the task. Sorry. No matter how scientific your data might be named and how elevated your own view of yourself might be. Its pretty much IT basics ... yeah. In fact its the **scientific method** and you fail at it if you think that you need to spam your memory with several GBs.

Comment: `malloc(4000000000ul)` works. I do not understand why the fact that it is a great number changes anything.

Comment: @specializt the OP wrote `GB`, not `GiB`.

Comment: @specializt *they're not. In fact they're everydays work. If you cant segment your data your skills arent quite up to the task.*  **WHY???**  On a machine that might have 512 GB of RAM - or even more - why on God's good Earth *should* I have to write code that uses "segmentation" on data to some arbitrary size based on hardware limits literally from the last century?  Next thing, you're going to be telling us 640K should be enough for everyone.

Comment: @specializt I dont understand your reaction. The fact it is 1<<32 or 4000000000 does not matter, my answer is the same...

Comment: Yes, its 32 Bit, also `signed` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx.

Comment: Guys, take this discussion to a chat room. This does not belong in the comments.

Comment: I agree with @specializt, most of the time if one needs to allocate such large memory, he's doing it wrong. Find alternate ways like dynamic programming or sparse arrays. Professionals who really need to use large memory won't ask such questions.

Comment: If your memory is bounded by 4GB look into memory mapping the file.  I have done that on linux to take the median of a thousand images consuming more than 100 GB or memory.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I think the problem that people have with specializt's comment is that he seems to suggest that having to allocate such large amounts of memory is _always_ wrong. Of course, throwing more hardware resources at a problem isn't always the right solution but neither is refusing to use extra hardware resources in appropriate solutions just because "it's bad".

Comment: @tangrs noone wrote that "its bad" - you completely made that up. Wasting resources, allocating memory **long** before you even access it is simply a beginners' mistake and will needlessly stress hardware - even modern RAM has its limit, spam several *(insert manufacturer / model-specific number here)* read/write cycles and you will see it start degrading. The root cause for such a decision is simple : lack of professional skill. Hey i know thats not what everybody wants to read but ... its reality. Every developer is able to load data on demand and/or segment it **with ease**

Comment: Files can be loaded in chunks, other streams can be read in chunks, datasets from databases can be read pagewise and so on. Thats really what every programming beginner learns in school in the first year. If you feel the need to spam your memory just because you've "got the resources for it" ... well ... you should think about switching jobs, probably do management and let the actual professionals do your old job. Im really sorry. Reality is harsh, i know. Dont let these words hurt you - you just gotta know it, thats all.

Comment: As always : the *(actual)* solution is somewhere in-between : **dont** throw additional hardware at problems and **dont** start loading your data bytewise just because you want to be as memory-efficient as possible but **do** act like a professional, choose a sensible chunk-size, establish proper loading / pagination *(pre-tested algorithms preferred)* and be happy with your non-increasing memory-usage and the fact that you did your job like you're supposed to. Welcome to the real world, also : the *(very)* scientific world.

Comment: @specializt Most of your points are slightly controversial but: "will needlessly stress hardware - even modern RAM has its limit, spam several (insert manufacturer / model-specific number here) read/write cycles and you will see it start degrading." is a completely ridiculous claim. Are you sure you're not thinking of non-volatile flash technologies?

Comment: Literally every memory in existence starts to degrade after extended usage - sometimes even normal usage, this is true for optical, magnetic, quantum-mechanical or even mechanical storage technology. RAM will degrade, **especially** if you keep using it like that - that *"completely riridulous claim"* is hard, factual, scientific, proven, observable reality. No, i will not google for you, sorry. Industrial-grade RAM usually is able to live much longer than consumer-grade and even intensive / extensive usage **might** not destroy noticeable amounts of cells after years - but you will lose a few

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contrary to your statement, `malloc()` will solve the problem, assuming you are using an implementation (which includes the compiler and library) that can produce a 64-bit executable, and have configured it to do so  (i.e. to build a 64-bit target).    Some toolchains are capable of building 64-bit targets but by default (e.g. as used in an associated IDE) will only produce a 32-bit executable.

If you are building a 32-bit target (i.e. producing a 32-bit executable) then, yes, `malloc()` will be limited to 4GB.  A 32-bit executable can be executed on a 64-bit system (assuming an operating system which permits that).   However, the program's use of `malloc()` will still be limited to 4GB in that case.

Which means you need to ensure you have a compiler that can build 64 bit programs AND use it to build a 64-bit target.

Of course, another question you should ask is whether you really need to allocate more than 4GB in a single chunk.   While there are circumstances where that is appropriate, more often than not, a program which needs to do that is a sign of poor or lazy design.

Comment: A 32-bit executable will be limited to 2GB (or 3, 3.5GB depending on system). It can't use 4GB except on Sparc Solaris where kernel and user space are separate

Comment: Sparc solaris is not the only OS which allows a 32-bit application to allocate 4GB.  In any event, this question is tagged C - in which case the maximum a 32-bit application can address is 4GB.  Whether an OS allows allocation of such an amount is another topic entirely - even on an OS which can allow allocation of such an amount by a 32-bit program, quotas or other administrative settings may disallow it.

Answer (score 5):

> Obviously using just malloc does not solve the problem.

Why? `size_t` should be large enough to cover all the address space your program has accessible, `malloc` takes a `size_t` and there are no standard reasons for why it shouldn't work.

I can unfortunately not try this on a Windows machine right now, but on a Linux machine this program works just fine (to show that there are no limitations in C that would prevent you from doing this):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t sz = 40000000000;
    char *a = malloc(sz);

    memset(a, 'a', sz);

    printf("%.4s", &a[sz-5]);

    return 0;
}
```

I allocate 40GB, fill it with the letter 'a' and then access it just to see that things worked. And they do. (Warning: don't run this program on a machine that doesn't have this much memory, systems can get quite unhappy when you overcommit memory).

Does this program work for you (size adjusted to what your hardware can do, obviously)? If yes, then you might have a problem with prototypes or data types for the size rather than a problem with `malloc`.

Comment: That will work just fine for about everybody, allocating 1345294336 bytes isn't that difficult :)  Integer overflow is a bitch.

Comment: @HansPassant You seem to be insinuating that sz gets truncated. Where do you think that truncation occurs?

Comment: @HansPassant LL is completely unnecessary here. You might want to read section 6.4.4.1 of the C99 or C11 standards. Specifically the bit that says "The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.". The list for decimal constants without a suffix contains long long.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Still not quite crystal what is supposed to happen when you target a 32-bit platform, afaik it is UB.

Comment: OP said he was on a 64 bit platform. I think we'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to allocate more than 4GB of memory in Windows is to just compile as a 64-bit program.  If you're using Visual Studio there are 2 ways to do that.

On the initial screen, at the top next to the "debug" dropdown there is a dropdown to specify what mode you want the program to compile to.  The default is "x86".  Click the dropdown and select "x64".

The second way is to click on the properties of the project.  On the next screen, next to "platform" is the Configuration Manager button.  Click it and the Configuration Manager screen displays.  On the "Active solution platform" click the dropdown and select "x64".

Then the normal `malloc` will work with more than 4GB.

This is using Visual Studio 2015.  I assume you can do similar in other versions of VS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 1) `size_t/SIZE_MAX` is smaller than available memory 2) and OP needs to perform a *single* large allocation:

Test your system's `calloc()`.

Depending on implementation, `calloc()` can allocate more than `SIZE_MAX` bytes.  The below will allocate `4*SIZE_MAX` bytes.

```
uint32_t *p;
size_t nmemb = SIZE_MAX;
p = calloc(nmemb, sizeof *p);
asset(p);

for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++) {
  p[i] = ...
}

free(p);
```

---

I've used this type of code when `size_t` was 16-bit and available memory was many times larger than that.

---

OTOH, some`calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)` will not allow an allocation where 
`(nmemb * size) > SIZE_MAX`.  YMMV